# Use the Implicit flow with OpenIdDict without having a Login/Register View on the Authorization Server

Tags: openiddict

What I'm trying to do is the following:

A SPA that communicates with a dotnet Core Wep API.
I want to use social logins.

I want to use a (Server-Side) authorization code flow.

I am leaning towards OpenIdDict for handling the JWT token authentication.

I set up the sample projects of OpenIdDict, specifically the ImplicitFlow and I got this to work.
But this sample uses a redirect to the Authorization Server for the actual login process.

Would it be possible to have these pages served by the SPA ass well?

It seems this has been done before, see: https://github.com/Kukks/openiddict-custom-grants-example

But I can't get that proof of concept to build anymore.

What I want to know is, whether Kukks proof of concept is still the way to go for implementing this and whether I'm doing the right thing by wanting it this way. Or am I opening a can of worms here and should I should I just load a page from the Authorization Server an stop complaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be possible to have these pages served by the SPA ass well?

No. With interactive flows (like code or implicit), the authorization server is supposed to be responsible of the authentication part, which is the only way to guarantee isolation between the authorization server and the client application, that cannot "see" the user credentials. Trying to work around that would almost defeat the whole purpose of these flows.

> What I want to know is, whether Kukks proof of concept is still the way to go for implementing this and whether I'm doing the right thing by wanting it this way.

If you own the client application and if redirecting your users to your authorization server (e.g using the implicit flow) is unacceptable for you, then yes, you may consider using the assertion flow.

In this case, the JS application will be responsible of handling the social login part (which means it will be directly registered with the external social providers. In the classic implicit flow, it would be the authorization server).

> Or am I opening a can of worms here and should I should I just load a page from the Authorization Server an stop complaining?

If you decide to implement this flow, you have to be extremely careful when implementing the external code/token validation routine to avoid what we call "confused deputy attacks".

The demo you're referring to is unfortunately vulnerable, as mentioned in this ticket: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/issues/13#issuecomment-250903091.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. In my case I *do* own the client application, so the assertion flow is an option. 

The wish for having the complete UI inside the SPA stems from the idea that if you build a SPA that communicates with a Web API, it just feels wrong to have the authentication UI on the server side. Part of the idea of having a Web API and a seperate SPA, is to have the UI inside the SPA and no UI on the server side.

You do make a lot of valid points though. Especially the point you make about isolation, and not trying to work around it, rings true.